# ScrollView shows content not right

Tags: swift, swift5

What may I have done wrong so that my `ScrollView` is not shown correctly in Simulator?
The Storyboard shows everything fine. The `ScrollView` is also scrollable.
[Scroll View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DYec.png)

Comment: Did you tried to set the Storyboard size to an iPhone 11 you are testing on? You can do that at the bottom of the interface. Is it than also displayed correctly?

Comment: Yes it is already on iPhone 11. It says -> View on iPhone 11 (wC hR) <-

Answer (score 0):

The simulator shows you what you get based on your "Auto-layout" constraints.
Looks like you have a lot of "hard-coded" distances which will not work well in different screen sizes.

Your scroll view is squeezed between 300 & 390 points which results in less space for "lastgames" image, so it gets scaled.

Try to play with Xcode's preview settings to see various screen sizes.

Comment: I tried now playing with those screen sizes and noticed that it looks right with iPhone 11 and wrong with all the other devices. So how can I avoid the thing called "Auto-Layout" constraints? What do I need to do?

Comment: You don't need to avoid them. You should learn how to use them so it will help you achieve what you want in all screen sizes. 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started
and
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: I read the documentation from Apple and it looks like I already use Autolayout correctly. I do exactly what they tell there. I use constraints and the rest gets done automatically. So I dont understand what I exactly did wrong. This only happens with ScrollView. ImageView or other things work. Images dont get scaled.

Comment: its not easy to see what you did wrong from an image, but for example when you say View.height = [scrollview].height , then no scrolling will ever happen... Instead you can give your View desired dimensions and constrain only top/leading/trailing to ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you can stretch the uiviews bounds which may not be the true dimensions because of your constraints. When that happens a little yellow arrow pops up (which is also visible in your screenshot). Try clicking this button to restore the bounds to you specified constraints (screenshot attached). [try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYUOp.png)